# How to get weight and bias that has a minimum total error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

Weight1, Weight2, bias1, bias2 are random list:

- `list1= [[(list of Weight1)], [(list of Weight2)], [(list of bias1)], [list of bias2)]]`
- l`ist2= [[(list of Weight1)], [(list of Weight2)], [(list of bias1)], [list of bias2)]]`
- `list3= [[(list of Weight1)], [(list of Weight2)], [(list of bias1)], [list of bias2)]]`

**popSize=3**

How to get weight and bias (Weight1, Weight2, bias1, bias2) that has a minimum tot_error

```
def findGStar(Weight1, Weight2, bias1, bias2):
    z1 = X_trainNorm.dot(Weight1) + bias1
    a1 = np.tanh(z1)
    z2 = a1.dot(Weight2) + bias2
    target = np.reshape(y_trainNorm,(-1,1))
    error = 0
    error = abs(z2-target)
    tot_error = sum(error)
    return tot_error

vec = []
for i in range(popSize):
    vector_new = findGStar(vector[i][0], vector[i][1], vector[i][2], vector[i][3])
    vec.append(vector_new)
vec.sort()
minimum = vec[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the results `pred_y_i` of the function whose weights you want to optimize, you calculate the MSE:

```
MSE = (1/N) * sum_i=1..N (y_i - pred_y_i)^2
```

Now you use an optimization algorithm of your choice. These can either use derivate (gradient descent, newton's method) or be derivate-free (particle swarm optimization).

For optimizations requiring derivation you want to do a partial derivation of your cost function (MSE) with respect to the weights. And update the weights according to some updating criterion (SGD, ADAM, Adagrad, etc..)

**UPDATE**

To find out which of the three lists has the best set of weights with respect to the MSE:

```
for i in range(popSize):
    vector_new = findGStar(vector[i][0], vector[i][1], vector[i][2], vector[i][3])
    vec.append(vector_new)
list_id = np.argmin(vec)
print('List {} contains the best parameter.'.format(list_id+1))
```

By sorting the `vec` list alone, you lose information about to which list each error belong to.

When we first get the `vec` vector, the indexes of errors in `vec` corresponds with indexes of `list#` in the `vector` list. So we can just find out which index holds the minimum error, and use that index to pull the `list#`.

Comment: For the exm: list3 is the best (minimum error) from other list(list1 & list2), then how to get values of list3, in the function i just return tot_error. i’m sorry, this is first time using python

Comment: Oh, you mean finding which of the three lists: list1, list2, list3 has the optimal weights?

Comment: but to find the minimum value using findGStar(): (function)

Comment: Are all the lists `list1`, `list2` and `list3` known at the beginning?